# Completion under weighted limits/colimits

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, enriched-category-theory, 2-categories

Is there any further reference besides "Basic Concepts of Enriched Categories" (Kelly) for completion under T-(weighted) limits/colimits?
(in which T is a set of weights)

Thank you in advance

Comment: What are F-(weighted) limits?

Comment: What does "F" refer to? I don't recall [F-categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/F-category) appearing in Kelly's book. Do you simply mean that you're interested in limits / colimits weighted by a (co)presheaf? If so, are you interested in the enriched case?

Comment: Sorry. I am aware of F-categories. But, instead, I was using a wrong notation for a set of weights.
Thank you for your answer. I am going to take a look in both references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extensive study of such cocompletions (thus also their duals - completions), together with some characterisation results, is given in the paper:

"A Representation Results for Free Cocompletions" by J. Power, G.L. Cattani and G. Winskel

Answer (score 3):

In the case of enriched categories, a review of the free cocompletion theory can be found in Kelly and Schmitt's [Notes on Enriched Categories with colimits of some class](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/14/17/14-17abs.html). I believe this is a more down-to-earth perspective than Power/Cattani/Winskel's 2-categorical approach.